# SpringMVC JPA Hibernate using maven fails: java.lang.AssertionError: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, junit

I am creating a site e commerce using springMVC jpa hibernate, when I made a JUnit to create tables I had this

**Error**:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource
>   [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested
>   exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
>   UP_BOUTIQUE] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
>         at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:91)
>         at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:43)
>         at org.sid.eboutique.TestJPA.test1(TestJPA.java:17)
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>         at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>         at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
>         at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>         at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
>         at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:539)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)

Here are the configuaration files:

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd ">
  <persistence-unit name="UP_BOUTIQUE" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.sid</groupId>
    <artifactId>eboutique</artifactId>
    <name>EBoutiqueV3</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.2.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Hibernate -->     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>  

        <!-- MySQL Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
   <bean id="datasource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
      <property name="url"
         value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sid_eboutique"></property>
      <property name="username" value="root"></property>
      <property name="password" value=""></property>
   </bean>
   <bean id="persistenceUnitManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
      <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="datasource"></property>
      <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
         <list>
            <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
         </list>
      </property>
   </bean>
   <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitMana`enter code here`ger"></property>
      <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="UP_BOUTIQUE"></property>
   </bean>
   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
      <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
   </bean>
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
   <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
</beans>



Thank you for your help :)
```

Comment: Format your answer. The error should be formatted like code. And keep other texts out of code format.

Comment: It cannot build the entityManagerFactory bean. Probably because of `<property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitMana`enter code here`ger">`

Comment: why not mention what is the rout cause exception nested at the root of that exception? because it is UTTERLY POINTLESS presenting an exception from the top of the stack ...